# Does Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles have special move/attack?

Tags: tmnt-4-turtles-in-time

Please tell if the Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles game "Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles IV - Turtles in Time" in SNES have special move/attack in them. E.g: How to throw enemy to screen.

I suck at playing this because they always grab me. I want to know more about this game. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

To throw: hit an enemy and he will be stunned, walk right next to him and punch
If you stand very close to him, you will throw him onto the screen easily, and if you stand a little less close, you will throw him forward and backward, and make huge damage to nearby enemy.

Special attack: it depends on the control type, for control type B, it is easier because you only need to press X. Special attack cut your health a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any special combos, but there are a couple cheats that could make your gaming easier.  Just in case you see cheats a spoilers, [follow the link](http://www.gamefaqs.com/snes/588779-teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles-iv-turtles-in-time/cheats) to the cheat codes.